# How to display my organization details on right side of the google SERP?

Tags: seo, google-search

When searching on Google, some organization details will display on the right side of the search result page that are realetd to my keywords.

Anybody knows how to display our data on that side?

See this example:

[image: Google search result page, showing information about "Google" in the sidebar]

Answer (score 3):

I found this great resource that goes into step by step instructions on how to do this. source: https://www.searchenginejournal.com/how-to-optimize-your-site-for-googles-answer-box/166084/

**Here are the quick highlights:**
To summarize, here’s what you should do if you have a website and want to get clicks from search in relation to a Google Answer Box.

- Start by finding out if there is a Google Answer Box that relates to
  content on your website or content that you could create for your
  website, as shown in the examples above.
- Create content that matches the Google Answer Box, goes into more
  depth, and make sure it is using the correct markup.
- Aim to be either the source of the Google Answer Box or the closest
  to the Google Answer Box as you can get.
- Make sure your page’s SEO title and meta description tell the
  searcher you have even better information than the Google Answer Box
  to encourage them to click on your link. Also, make sure it includes
  the query the person would search to find the Google Answer Box.
- Build links to your Google Answer Box content using anchor text that
  matches the Google Answer Box call to action (if you have software)
  or the query the person would search to find the Google Answer Box.

I am playing around with some free Wordpress plugins that automatically add schema. You can view more on SEO and other marketing help on my blog here: [**http://www.renowebdesigner.com**](http://www.renowebdesigner.com)

Answer (score 2):

That’s coming from Google’s [Knowledge Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knowledge_Graph).

If you are the "authority" (e.g., for a search for "google", the authority is Google), structured data on your site can be used by Google to show more information in that sidebar. That would be **Knowledge Graph cards** ([details](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/guides/intro-structured-data)). An example is [Corporate Contacts](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/corporate-contacts).

Comment: If place the `application/ld+json` codes on my site, It show on rightside of the google SERP?

Comment: @MikeTavish: Not just any JSON-LD. Google uses a few specific parts of Schema.org structured data for this purpose (like the linked Corporate Contacts), and only for sites that have such a Knowledge Graph sidebar.

Comment: Is it possible to add My organization to Google's Knowledge Graph

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have GMB Page for your website and make sure that your profile is 100% updated. It is called a knowledge graph. Basically, there are two types of graph,

1. Local Knowledge Graph
2. Branded Knowledge Graph

I hope that you have updated the following things on GMB page:

1. Business name
2. Business category & sub-category
3. Services which your offering
4. Contact num
5. Website link & appointment link
6. Explain about your business
7. Mark the exact location on the map
8. Add labels

To implement the knowledge graph for your business. I'm not aware of which website platform you're using.

**Case1:** If you're using WP website you can directly download knowledge graph plugin and update all your social links. At the same time make sure that your website doesn't have any issues. Check with structured data testing tool.

**Case2:** If you developed a website on another platform I request you to implement schema.org on the website with the help of the developer. The complete guide is available in webmaster tools.

Hope I have answered your question.